# Scraping keywords on PHP page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape the keywords inside the dropdown table of this webpage https://www.aeaweb.org/jel/guide/jel.php

The problem is that the drop-down menu of each item prevents me from scraping the table directly because it only takes the heading and not the inner content of each item.

```
rvest::read_html("https://www.aeaweb.org/jel/guide/jel.php") %>%
    rvest::html_table()
```

I thought of scraping each line that starts with `Keywords:` but I do not get how can I do that. Seems like the HTML is not showing the items inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

A `RSelenium` solution,

```
#Start the server 
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(
  browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
#Navigate to the url
remDr$navigate("https://www.aeaweb.org/jel/guide/jel.php")
#xpath of the table 
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/main/div/section/div[4]') -> out
#get text from the table
out <- out$getElementText()
out= out[[1]]
```

Split using `stringr` package

```
    library(stringr)
    str_split(out, "\n", n = Inf, simplify = FALSE)
[[1]]
 [1] "A General Economics and Teaching"                                                            
 [2] "B History of Economic Thought, Methodology, and Heterodox Approaches"                        
 [3] "C Mathematical and Quantitative Methods"                                                     
 [4] "D Microeconomics"                                                                            
 [5] "E Macroeconomics and Monetary Economics"                                                     
 [6] "F International Economics"                                                                   
 [7] "G Financial Economics"                                                                       
 [8] "H Public Economics"                                                                          
 [9] "I Health, Education, and Welfare"                                                            
[10] "J Labor and Demographic Economics"                                                           
[11] "K Law and Economics"                                                                         
[12] "L Industrial Organization"                                                                   
[13] "M Business Administration and Business Economics; Marketing; Accounting; Personnel Economics"
[14] "N Economic History"                                                                          
[15] "O Economic Development, Innovation, Technological Change, and Growth"                        
[16] "P Economic Systems"                                                                          
[17] "Q Agricultural and Natural Resource Economics; Environmental and Ecological Economics"       
[18] "R Urban, Rural, Regional, Real Estate, and Transportation Economics"                         
[19] "Y Miscellaneous Categories"                                                                  
[20] "Z Other Special Topics"
```

To get the `Keywords` for **History of Economic Thought, Methodology, and Heterodox Approaches**

```
out1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="cl_B"]')
out1$clickElement()
        
out1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/main/div/section/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]')
out1$getElementText()
    [[1]]
    [1] "Keywords: History of Economic Thought"
```

Comment: What I want are actually the keywords inside each drop down menu not the headers

Comment: But in this case, how can I generalize it to retrieve all the keywords on the page? Suppose I want also the keywords of B16, how should I approach that? I need to hardcode every path